# Bat file allowing for java updates with in the path

Tags: java, version

I have bat file that currently contains

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -jar
```

This issue is ever time the VM gets updated with new version of Java the bat file fails

See below previous older version bat file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" -jar
```

How to program for such changes?
thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1):

#### The issue is every time the VM gets updated with new version of Java the bat file fails

When you correctly install Java you should:

- Set `JAVA_HOME` to point to the root directory of your Java installation:

  ```
  setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_231"
  ```
- Add the Java bin directory to your path:

  ```
  setx PATH "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin";%PATH%
  ```
- Close and restart any `cmd` shells to pick up the new variables

Then change your bat file to:

```
java.exe" -jar
```

See [Installing the JDK Software](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#CHDEBCCJ) and [Setting JAVA_HOME and PATH and CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for more information.